# What's the purpose of the FLOOD table in my Drupal 7 database?

Tags: 7

I want to improve the performance of my Drupal website, which is why I am trying to remove unwanted tables.

What's the purpose of the *flood* table?

Comment: I don't understand those 3 down votes.

Comment: @Randell I would guess the users are finding the question not much helpful. Finding the purpose of a database table used by Drupal is not that difficult. This is not the type of questions we want, which why it gets down-voted: Users are sending a clear message to the OP.

Comment: I would also add there are better way to improve performance that is not removing database tables, which is probably the last of your worries.

Comment: Even though deleting this core table is indeed NOT recommended, I think this is a "good" question. It does need some edit suggestions, which I just submitted. And looking at the (great) answers only confirms to "me" that it is indeed a good question. Therefor +1 from me. Anybody familiar with something like "There are no bad (stupid) questions!"?

Comment: As a user who found this question helpful, I disagree w/ kiamlaluno both WRT to the idea it's easy to find the purpose of a DB table in Drupal (is anything about Drupal easy to find?) and that users are sending a "clear" message: I find downvoting nothing but _ambiguous_. Also, when I try looking for "what type of questions _we_ want" (do you speak for all of _us_?), the Help Center indicates to me at least that this is an appropriate question. kiamlaluno himself seemed to think a question about the authmap table's purpose was appropriate enough to answer [here](/questions/63121).

Answer (score 7):

It is not a good practice to remove the core tables of drupal.You can uninstall your unwanted modules .

FYI,
flood table is used to control the number of events, like contacting someone. 
event is the name of the event (for eg. contact) hostname is the hostname of the visitor and timestamp is the timestamp of the event. By sotring these in the flood it's easy to count how many users your hostname contacted in the last hour. As all hostname based mechanisms, this is flawed as well, but binding to a session would be even more trouble -- too easy to circumvent.

Taken from this comment by chx: http://drupal.org/node/164983#comment-589458

Comment: I was just bit  (few secs) late to post this same answer. so I just deleted my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Dont delete the Flood table. You can try to throw away gears from your car, if you are top-notch specialist, and know for sure, that your car will need no breaks (in some cases, people will have that one-time ride, hopefully no one gets hurt besides themselves).

Flood table is used to store data about bruteforce login attempts, blocking such people. So its does not contain lots of data unless someone is trying to break you. And if someone is, then you do want that table :)

On a higher level, modules use tables to write data. So, if you drop or clear a table, that will break the site in some cases, and cause it being slower in some (emptying the caches, for instance, will cause them being rebuilt).

The right way to minimize the amount of tables, is to uninstall the modules you dont need, via Drupal's uninstall interface on the modules page. From my experience, however, what can really slow Drupal, is when you have lots of content and lots and visitors, and lots of views. Otherwise, trying to break your site by deleting some service table is useless. You can as well try to make your boat lighter by throwing your life jacket overboard. Wont really lighten the boat, but will make yourself problems.